# User SID copy/paste using command line?

Tags: command-line, cmd, sid

Can user SID be copied from registry (or whatever) and pasted to a txt file using command line only (Windows 7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via WMIC

```
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid | findstr /b /C:"S-1" > file.txt
```

Via WHOAMI (duplicate percent signs if used in batch file)

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %f in ('whoami /user /FO CSV /NH') do echo %~f > file.txt
```