# wmic useraccount SID blank spaces/empty lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I have this [two commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766590/user-sid-copy-paste-using-command-line) to get SID useraccount

```
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid | findstr /b /C:"S-1" > file.txt
```

or

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %f in ('whoami /user /FO CSV /NH') do echo %~f > file.txt
```

both cases (file.txt) contain blank spaces/empty lines. I try to remove with

```
findstr /r /v "^$"
```

But it is impossible. How can remove all blank spaces/empty lines to get only SID number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
        wmic  path win32_useraccount 
        where name^="%username%" 
        get   sid^,status /format:csv
    ') do (
        >"file.txt" <nul set /p"=%%a"
    )
```

That will skip headers, include an additional field so the `sid` is the second field in the record (in `csv` format the `node` field gets included) so we can avoid an ending carriage return in the output of the `wmic` command (each line ends in `CR+CR+LF`) and the output is sent to the file using a `set /p` command with the input stream reading from `nul` device. This way the output to the file will not include the ending `CR+LF` that is included with `echo`

The same code for in the `whoami` version

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
        whoami /user /FO CSV /NH
    ') do (
        >"file.txt" <nul set /p"=%%~a"
    )
```

Comment: thanks works with whoami. wmic generates an error because csv format [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673057/wmic-error-invalid-xsl-format-in-windows7)

Answer (score 2):

This batch file can did the trick :

```dos
@echo off
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set myvar=%%a
      goto :loop_end
   )   
)

:loop_end
echo SID=%myvar%
echo %myvar% > SID_%username%.txt
pause>nul
Start "" SID_%username%.txt
```

For the second method of `whoami /user /FO CSV /NH` ,you can take a look at this :

**[Get SID for current logged in domain user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350842/how-to-get-active-session-user-sid?answertab=active#tab-top)**

Comment: great but the loop never end

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it, WMIC:

```dos
for /f "skip=1" %a in ('"wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid"') do @for %b in (%a) do @(>file.txt echo(%b)
```

and with WhoAmI

```dos
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %a in ('whoami /user /FO CSV /NH') do @(>file.txt echo(%a)
```

both in the command line to match the question *(ignoring the batch-file tag)*.

Comment: sorry. this doesn't work. I recommend you first try to verify commands that work before publishing

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out that there was a typo, it would have helped had you told me which of the two lines of code contained it though. I cannot test most of the code I provide as I rarely have access to a Windows PC.

Comment: bad quality code. You should test it before publishing